# How to select case when more column for inserting?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i need your help to insert into from select but my query is too complex for me. My logic is below

```
    INSERT INTO TheTable(A,CustomerNo,item,B,C,D)
    SELECT DISTINCT

        case when ((select count(*) from hesap  where CustomerNo=e.CustomerNo)0) then 
select top 1, A,CustomerNo,item+1,B,C,D
from dbo.Table1  order by ekno desc

)  else select 100,e.CustomerNo,e.item,0,e.defterid,'C'
from Table2 e end
```

But i can not do that...

Comment: Would you care to accept an answer?

Comment: "I can not do that" does not describe a problem very well. I assume that you already know that your syntax is not valid, so can you explain exactly what you're trying to do? `IF...THEN...` might be an easier solution here than a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `case` on *column basis* only.

What you can do is `UNION`ing two selects, and insert the result. Something like

```
INSERT INTO TheTable(A,CustomerNo,item,B,C,D)
SELECT ... 
 WHERE (select count(*) from hesap  where CustomerNo=e.CustomerNo) = 0
UNION
SELECT select 100,e.CustomerNo,e.item,0,e.defterid,'C'
 WHERE (select count(*) from hesap  where CustomerNo=e.CustomerNo) > 0
```

I'm sorry, I cannot always follow your Select, but I hope you got the idea. You have to separate the 2 possibilities before you UNION them, so only 1 row can exist for each original row.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the comma after top 1 Like this:

```
INSERT INTO TheTable(A,CustomerNo,item,B,C,D)
        SELECT DISTINCT
        case when ((select count(*) from hesap  where CustomerNo=e.CustomerNo)0) then 
        select top(1) A,CustomerNo,item+1,B,C,D
        from dbo.Table1  order by ekno desc
        )  
else select 100,e.CustomerNo,e.item,0,e.defterid,'C'
from Table2 e end
```

Comment: It looks like you have selected 7 columns(1, A,CustomerNo,item+1,B,C,D) to insert into 6(A,CustomerNo,item,B,C,D) columns. Correct me please if I am wrong.. I have edited my answer, you can try 'TOP(1)' syntax.